# How to make clickable listview in android using kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new in android development with kotlin  . I am trying to make clickable listview items but not getting good resource.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not much different from how you'd do it in Java since Kotlin uses Java's frameworks/libraries and its JVM. Just apply the necessary Kotlin plugins and configurations in Android Studio, convert the Java code to Kotlin, and then refer to the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html) for potential bug fixes and whatnot.